# Black Market and game setup

Tags: dominion, game-setup

In a game where Black Market is being used what happens to the setup phase of cards in the Black Market deck?

In particular if the Black Market deck contains a card such as Young Witch or Trade Route when is the setup for those cards performed?

The setup phase of Young Witch introduce an 11th kingdom card pile. Will this pile be available in every game with a Young With in the Black Market deck, even if the Young With has not yet been revealed?

Trade Route requires a coin on every victory supply pile and these being moved to the Trade Route mat as cards are being gained. Do these coin movements happen before the Trade Route is revealed from the Black Market deck?

I can imagine a few possible answers, but I haven't found any official answer:

- Setup for every card in the Black Market deck is done at the start of the game.
- Setup is done when the card is revealed from the Black Market deck.
- Setup is done when the card is bought from the Black Market deck.
- Setup is never done. (This would make Trade Route almost worthless and Young Witch a bit more powerful)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the first option; all setup things are done at the start of a game. A card being in the Black Market deck acts just like a card in the Supply for this purpose.

Strangely enough, this rule is not listed in the official Black Market FAQ. But it is listed in several other places.

- From the [Cornucopia rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=558):

> If you are using the promotional card Black Market, and Young Witch is in the Black Market deck, put out a Bane pile for Young Witch.

- From the Baker FAQ in the [Guilds rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=1767):

> In games using this card, each player starts the game with a Coin token. This includes games using the promo card Black Market in which Baker is in the Black Market deck.

- From the [Alchemy rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=503):

> Also add the Potion pile if you are using the promotional card Black Market, and the Black Market deck includes at least one card with [P] in the cost. If you do not have any cards with [P] in the cost in the Supply or in the Black Market deck, do not use the Potion pile in this game.

- From the Trade Route FAQ in the [Prosperity rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_361_gameRules.pdf):

> If you are using Black Market and Trade Route is in the
>   Black Market deck, put tokens on Victory card piles at the start of the game.

Although the Nocturne rulebook does not mention using an Heirloom when the appropriate card is in the Black Market, [Donald X confirmed that you do](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=17770.msg727894#msg727894):

> Everyone's favorite rules question: If these kingdom cards are in the Black Market deck, are the Heirlooms used?
>
> > I recommend not putting them in the Black Market deck, but yes, you do all setup for Black Market deck cards.

Similarly, the Dark Ages rulebook does not mention Black Market, but if there are any Looters in the Black Market deck, then you include Ruins in the Supply.

Note that if Young Witch is in the Black Market deck; Black Market itself cannot be the Bane card; because the Bane has to be a newly added 11th pile.

Comment: You are right. I verified the rules for Cornucopia (which is the only of the mentioned extensions that I own myself), and that sentence is in there but not in the section describing Young Witch, which is where I initially looked.